# Looking for a hadith full version about expressing love to a person

Tags: hadith, reference-request

I am looking for a narration full version and reference.
In the narration, the Prophet SAWS and sahabas were sitting. A sahaba said he loves another sahaba. The
Prophet instructed him to go and tell the other man he loves him.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A man was with the Prophet (ﷺ) when another man passed by and the
> former said: "O Messenger of Allah! I love this man (for Allah's
> sake)". Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) asked, "Have you informed him?" He
> said, "No". Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) then said, "Tell him (that you love
> him)". So he went up to the man and said to him, "I love you for the
> sake of Allah;" and the other replied, "May Allah, for Whose sake you
> love me, love you." [Riyad as-Salihin 385]

Answer (score 1):

The hadith appears in [Sunan abi Dawod](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/43/353) (where you my find a special subsection entitled:"Chapter: When one man loves another because of some good that he sees"):

> Narrated Anas ibn Malik:
> A man was with the Prophet (ﷺ) and a man passed by him and said: Messenger of Allah! I love this man. The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) then asked: Have you informed him? He replied: No. He said: Inform him. He then went to him and said: I love you for Allah's sake. He replied: May He for Whose sake you love me love you!

Imam an-Nawawi qualified its narrator chain as "sahih" and al-Albani qualified the hadith as hassan.

In the same section you may find a more general hadith saying:

> Narrated Al-Miqdam ibn Ma'dikarib:
> The Prophet (ﷺ) said: When a man loves his brother, he should tell him that he loves him.
> ([Sunan abi Dawod](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/43/352) and see also in [al-Adab al-Mufrad](https://sunnah.com/adab/30/6))

This hadith is qualified as sahih in Sunan abi Dawod and as hassan sahih in imam al-Bukhari's longer version in al-Adab al-Mufrad by al-Albani.